# Integrating Multiple WordPress Plugins into One Dashboard

Tags: plugin-development

I have created multiple plugins for WordPress, each with its own dashboard and slug, but with different settings. I am looking for some help and ideas on how to connect all of these plugins together seamlessly.

Ideally, I would like for a user who purchases multiple plugins to be able to install them without any errors. I want all the plugins to appear in one dashboard and be accessible on one subpage.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Off the top of my head: first plugin to load owns the dashboard, and can detect this by e.g. using a fixed class name and testing if the class has been registered; then use hooks for all plugins to add their own sections to the dashboard, filters for columns on tables, etc. But there must be examples out there already. Will try and write a better answer later.

Comment: This a really broad question, there are multiple ways to go about doing this.  Each of the plugins could have the same 'parent' function that establishes the dashboard and then wrapped in a `if( !function_exists( 'dashboard_function' ) ):` then, in that function there's a hook and the rest of the pieces that load into the dashboard all use the hook to fire themselves in.  You can set priorities on them as well to get them always loading in the same order.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.